# Viability of laughing gas as a weapon

Tags: science-based, weapons, chemistry, biochemistry, gas

How effective would it be? Presume that the nitrous oxide is freely available to the user (e.g. "magically" [hand-wave] produced) and that they are immune to any effects. How far would it really disable/harm?

Comment: Might be better suited to Biology SE.

Comment: Obligatory Monty Python (the pre-internet version of Obligatory XKCD): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ienp4J3pW7U

Comment: I am sure the Joker knows something about it 
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfpDTHtZ4C0

Comment: Just remember it would be a war crime like mustard gas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make you laugh to death like the gas The Joker makes. Part of the way it works is it reduces the amount of oxygen getting into your blood so if there was a high enough percentage in the air you could cause brain damage. But this would either have to take place in a confined space or have you dump *a lot* of gas on an area to be effective this way.

In short, theres absolutely better weapons you could use but if you want to gas people in a room GlaDos style the option is definately there.

I got my info from here: 
http://www.treatment4addiction.com/drugs/inhalants/nitrous-oxide/

Answer (score 2):

According to what I can read online, the effects of laughing gas strongly vary with dose: they go from inhibition of fear or euphoria to numbness or sleep.

While it is desirable to have an incapacitated enemy, an enemy with a diminished sense of fear or euphoria is way less desirable, for obvious reasons.

This is probably why it has not been used as chemical weapon.

Comment: I think the reason why it has not been used as a chemical weapon is that there are other agents which are far cheaper to produce while also being far more lethal. Chlorine, for example.

Comment: No fear means that enemy will die easily. There is a known disability that makes people unable to feel fear. People with it don't live long. Certainly desirable in an enemy. What you don't want is enemy to be brave — but that's another thing.